# Java parenthesis replacement with empty string

Tags: java, string, replace

Why doesn't the first line replace "(" with an empty string , while the second one does?

```
 public static void main(String []args){
     String a="This(rab)(bar)";
     a=a.replace("\\(",""); //First
     String b=a.replaceFirst("\\(","");//Second
    System.out.println(a + " "+b);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [`replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). If your IDE shows you the method signatures, you'll see:

[image]

See how `replace` accepts a plain old `target` whereas `replaceFirst` accepts a `regex`?

`"\\("` is a *regex* that means "a single open parenthesis". `replace` doesn't treat the strings you pass in as regexes. It will simply try to find a backslash followed by an open parenthesis, which does not exist in your string.

If you want to use `replace`, just use `"("`.

Comment: So isn't this "(" a regex?
It's a string isn't it?

Comment: @ErikNouroyan `(` is not a valid regex. It doesn’t mean “match an open parenthesis”. `\(` is valid regex that means “Match an open parenthesis”. In java string literals, the backslash gets escapes to become `\\`.

Comment: why does replaceFirst  take "\\\( " as a single paranthesis insted of backslash and single paranthesis?

Comment: Because `\(` is a regex that means “one opening parenthesis” and `replaceFirst` accepts a regex. `(` on its own has special meaning in regex - start of a capturing group, so you need to escape it with `\` to mean “one open parenthesis”. @ErikNouroyan

Comment: Can you share a valid link to learn more about regexes, please?

Comment: @ErikNouroyan  if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 3):

For `replace` to work you should write:

```
a=a.replace("(",""); //First
```

or use `replaceAll` if you want to pass a `regex`:

```
a=a.replaceAll("\\(",""); //First
```

`replace` accepts a sequence of characters to replace:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

Therefore, in your case it attempts to replace the 3 characters "\(", not just the single character "(".

Comment: In that case why doesn't this work?
a=a.replace("(",""); //First

Comment: @ErikNouroyan `replace` does not expect a regex as the first argument. Therefore it tried to replace the actual sub-string "\\\(", which is not present in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is running in `replace` with several characters and, therefore, what it will look for is `\` and `(`, so that this does not happen **the quotation marks should only contain the character to replace** :

```
    a = a.replace("(", ""); // First
```

Next I leave a sniper with the original proposal and the fixed one :

```
public class Main {

    private static final Main initRun = new Main();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "This(rab)(bar)";

        System.out.println("Original");
        initRun.runOriginal(a);

        System.out.println("Fixed");
        initRun.runFixed(a);

        // Output
        // Original
        // This(rab)(bar)
        // Thisrab)(bar)
        // Fixed
        // Thisrab)bar)
        // Thisrab)bar)
    }

    /**
     * Execute the original proposal
     *
     * @param a String for replace
     */
    void runOriginal(String a) {
        a = a.replace("\\(", ""); // First
        String b = a.replaceFirst("\\(", "");// Second
        System.out.println(a + "\n" + b);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the fixed proposal
     *
     * @param a String for replace
     */
    void runFixed(String a) {

        a = a.replace("(", ""); // First
        String b = a.replaceFirst("\\(", "");// Second
        System.out.println(a + "\n" + b);
    }
}
```